# Unable to activate windows 10 and Forgot to see the windows 7 product key

Tags: windows-10, setup

I installed a windows 10 copy I can't activate the windows 10. I was using windows 7.I forgot te see my product key.so if i install windows 7 again can i find my previous product key?

What should I do?

Comment: Your Windows 7 key is printed on the COA sticker attached to your device.  You will be unable to install Windows 7 without that key.  As already indicated you will be unable to upgrade to Windows 10 for free.  Even if the upgrade offer was still valid, you would need the license key, in order to install Windows 10 for the first time.

Comment: https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/
and https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/upgrade-to-windows-10-free
and https://www.techsupportall.com/upgrade-windows-7-to-windows-10-for-free-even-in-2018/
So, as I told you before you can still upgrade for free any wont need to buy a key(Most probably)

Comment: Also, open command prompt and type:
"wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey"
,without the quotes and check if it will return a key

Comment: No it doesn't.how can I roll back I don't have the full

Comment: Hey i have a key

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upgrade freely from Windows 7 to Windows 10.
There was a period of one year when this was possible, but this offer has ended
years ago.

There is no point in re-installing Windows 7, because (1) it will not help
in upgrading to Windows 10, and (2) this will not restore the old Windows 7
serial.

You will need to buy a Windows 10 serial key in order to activate it.
There is no other way.